# GIT connection avaible login/password/url repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab, aws-codecommit

How can we know if login + password + url of repo git is valid ?

Without clone whole project ...

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Brute-force attack?

Comment: That depends entirely on the hosting service that is used.

Comment: I want to do a CICD platform. I also need to have access to git to test on different branch

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a wrong branch to checkout

```
git clone --branch nonexistent git@address.com:user/repo.git
```

> fatal: Remote branch nonexisting not found in upstream origin

Although it results in an error, it is different than other errors:

- Inexisting repository: `$ git clone git@address.com:user/nonexisting.git`

  > fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
- Wrong Credentials: `$ git clone wrong@address.com:user/repo.git`

  > wrong@address.com's password:

---

Using ssh you can use the following command to check for access:

```
ssh -T git@address

> Welcome to GitLab
```

Note that this does not check for validity of the specified repository on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) to access remote repository without cloning.